# Connecting multiple Sliders in Bokeh - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, slider, bokeh

hope someone can solve my issue - I am at my wit´s end.

**I wanna link three sliders in a Bokeh circle figure. The overall sum should always be 1. (E.g. when one slider is being used the others must decrease therefore, so that the sum is always 1)**

**Update: There is no condition how the sliders should react. It would be nice if both are decreasing simultaneously but I wouldn´t mind if not...**

So far, I was able to implement all sliders, yet they just work independently. I already attempted to customize the callbacks with JavaScript, but this goes way over my head.

It would be totally awesome if somebody could enlighten me, 
here is the code:

````
import statistics as stats
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider,CustomJS, TextInput, Span,CategoricalColorMapper
from bokeh.models.tools import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6

Purchasing = [91.88405797, 85.9986413 , 84.25271739, 89.11684783, 75.50271739,
       87.31431159, 90.36458333, 94.08061594, 88.13405797, 82.7807971 ,
       86.7798913 , 88.17028986, 86.07789855, 91.88405797, 91.88405797,
       91.88405797, 96.5307971 , 96.15036232]
TechSupport = [ 98.83534137,  77.49665328,  80.20080321,  87.1686747 ,
        72.40963855,  69.79919679,  91.56626506,  87.34939759,
        91.66666667,  84.84366036,  88.95582329,  91.56626506,
        92.85140562,  88.95582329, 100.        , 100.        ,
        99.11646586, 100.        ]
Materials = [82.59355962, 72.82816715, 72.6904661 , 82.59355962, 81.17238618,
       76.65485515, 81.13385703, 86.30709871, 86.94516971, 86.56883131,
       82.59355962, 86.38817563, 86.94516971, 82.59355962, 82.59355962,
       86.94516971, 82.59355962, 82.59355962]

y = [0.625, 0.625, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.625, 0.625, 0.5 ,
       0.625, 0.75 , 0.325, 0.575, 1.125, 0.375, 0.45 , 0.575, 0.325]

Names = ['Company 1', 'Company 2', 'Company 3', 'Company 4', 'Company 5',
       'Company 6', 'Company 7', 'Company 8', 'Company 9', 'Company 10',
       'Company 11', 'Company 12', 'Company 13', 'Company 14',
       'Company 15', 'Company 16', 'Company 17', 'Company 18']

Purchasing_Weight   = 0.368
TechSupport_Weight = 0.249
Materials_Weight = 0.383

#xmin, xmax = min(x), max(x)
#ymin, ymax = min(y), max(y)

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=Materials,z=TechSupport,w=Purchasing,y=y,Names=Names,Category=Category))

# Set up plot
plot = figure(
        title = "Performence to Risk Dispertion: Q1",
        x_axis_label = "Performance",y_axis_label = "Business Risk",
        #x_range=(xmin, xmax),y_range=(ymin, ymax),
        plot_width = 1000,
        plot_height = 500,
        tools ="pan,zoom_in,zoom_out,reset,save")



# Tools
hover = HoverTool()
#hover.tooltips= [ ("Company: ", "$Names"),("(x,y)", "($x, $y)")]
hover.tooltips = """
<div>
    <h3><font size="+1">@Names</font></h3>
    <h3><font size="+1">@Category</font></h3>
    <div><strong><font size="+0">Perf: </strong>@x</font><div>
    <div><strong><font size="+0">Risk: </strong>@y</font><div>
</div>
"""
plot.add_tools(hover)


# ascribe plot
plot.circle(x= "x", y= "y",
         size=10, line_width=2,
         source = source)


slider1 = Slider(start=0.0, end=1, value=Purchasing_Weight,step=0.01, title='Purchasing_Weight')
slider2 = Slider(start=0.0, end=1, value=TechSupport_Weight, step=0.01, title='TechSupport_Weight')
slider3 = Slider(start=0.0, end=1, value=Materials_Weight, step=0.01, title='Materials_Weight')
def callback(attr, old, new): 

    #while slider1.value + slider2.value + slider3.value > 1:
    #    slider2.value - 0.01

    Purchasing_Weight = slider1.value
    TechSupport_Weight = slider2.value
    Materials_Weight = slider3.value

 #  new_data = dict(x = np.multiply(Materials,Purchasing_Weight),z=TechSupport,w=Purchasing,y=y,Names=Names,Category=Category)    
    new_data = dict(x = np.multiply(Materials,Materials_Weight)+np.multiply(TechSupport,TechSupport_Weight)+np.multiply(Purchasing,Purchasing_Weight),
                    y=y,Names=Names,Category=Category)    
    source.data = new_data
    hover.tooltips = """
    <div>
        <h3><font size="+1">@Names</font></h3>
        <h3><font size="+1">@Category</font></h3>
        <div><strong><font size="+0">Perf: </strong>@x</font><div>
        <div><strong><font size="+0">Risk: </strong>@y</font><div>
    </div>
    """
    plot.add_tools(hover)


callback2 = CustomJS(args=dict(sider1=slider1, slider2=slider2), code="""
    slider2.end = slider1.value;
    source.change.emit();
""")

slider1.on_change('value', callback)
#slider1.js_on_change('value', callback2)

slider2.on_change('value', callback)
slider3.on_change('value', callback)

# Set up layouts and add to document
layout = column(slider1,slider2,slider3, plot)

curdoc().add_root(layout)
import os
os.system(r'cd /D C:\Users\PathofDocument') 
os.system("bokeh serve --show NameofScript.py")```

####Cheers and thanks in advance for any help!####
````

Comment: You've only said *x + y + z = 1* but that is not enough information to fully determine how the other sliders should react. If I lower *x* by 0.4 then you could either: i) raise *y* by 0.4, or ii) raise *y* by 0.2 and *z* by 0.2, or iii) any of an infinite number of other combinations that satisfy the sum condition. Which is correct to do? Mathematically speaking, there has to be another governing relationship between the three variables for this to make sense at all. That's before getting in to any of the implementation details at all.

Comment: Hi bigreddot, thanks for your reply. There is no condition how they should react. It would be nice if both are decreasing simultaneously but I wouldn´t mind if not... Those 3 weights are applied to 3 different categories, and I wanna see how differences in weightings interfere with the data, and eventually change the scatter. 
hope this does clarify the issue...

Comment: It does not. Until you decide and define more relations, the problem is mathematically under-specified and there is no unique solution (e.g. that could be implemented in code). Deciding what you want to happen is a necessary first step.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. Each slider is related to one category (and being multiplied with this specific category). The relation is naturally bounded to 100% (therefore 1). The weights can therefore end up distributed equally, on just one slider, and so on....
If I increase one slider, the other sliders (which are not being used) should decrease simultaneously (from their current values) so that my overall score always equals 1.  
All three together eventually end up as the "x"- value on my scatter plot. 
hope this clarify my issue in mathematical terms more properly?

Comment: I guess we are talking past each other. You have to specify *exactly how* you want the other two sliders to react, in a way that covers every possible situation (by specifying more relationships). There are literally, mathematically, an infinite number of solutions to the underdetermined system *x+y+z=1*. In order to actually implement anything like you describe at all in code, you have to *pick one specific actual behavior* to implement. It's not sufficient to say "the other two decrease simultaneously". Decrease  *how, exactly?* How should the decrease be split among the two?

Comment: I am sorry, guess this is one of the problem why I wasn´t able to implement it: I didn´t think about it in such mathematical terms.
z + y +  z = 1 
0.20 + 0.50 + 0.30 = 1
 
--> increase z = 0.6, should result in
0.6+ 0.30 + 0.10 = 1

--> increase z=1,
1+ 0 + 0 = 1

--> decrease again z = 0.5,
0.5 + 0.25 + 0.25 = 1

--> increase y = 0.50,
0.375 + 0.5 + 0.125 = 1
.... 
This should hold regardless which slider I´m lower or higher. 
Hope I got it this time :D